# Creating Effectivity Dates to model relations in a table for 1-many relationships

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-modeling

The table below represents student enrollments in a class. I want to create a field in a view called enrolled_end, that is only to be populated if the student completes the class. This view is going to be ran in real time so current date is relevant. As you can see a single student can enroll in many classes, can drop out of a class and re-enroll at a later date - so I want a record to capture the effectivity of when they enrolled/dropped out and when the started new again. As well, I am given to actual start_date rather only a load_timestamp which can get conflated with column value changes (ie hair color below).

I have a table below that can be created in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f79084

**(please note, 1990-03-18 is supposed to represent NULL)**

```
CREATE TABLE class_enrollments (
  student_id VARCHAR(100),
  load_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  class_id VARCHAR(100),
  hair_color VARCHAR(100),
  class_end_date TIMESTAMP,
  dropout_date   TIMESTAMP
);
    INSERT INTO class_enrollments VALUES
    ('1', '2023-03-17', 'math', 'red', '2024-03-18', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2021-03-17','english', 'red',  '2022-03-18', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2023-03-18', 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-18', '1990-03-18'),
    ('2', '2023-03-19','math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('3', '2021-03-20', 'math', 'blue', '2022-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('4', '2023-03-21', 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('4', '2023-07-01', 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '2023-07-01'),
    ('5', '2023-03-22', 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2021-07-01','english', 'red',  '2022-03-18', '2021-07-01'),
    ('1', '2023-03-23', 'english', 'red', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18'),
    ('3', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '1990-03-18')
    ;
```

Below is the sample output I desire for the view:

```
CREATE TABLE es_class_enrollments (
  student_id VARCHAR(100),
  enrolled_start TIMESTAMP,
  class_id VARCHAR(100),
  hair_color VARCHAR(100),
  enrolled_end TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO es_class_enrollments VALUES
    ('1', '2023-03-17', 'math', 'red', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2021-03-17','english', 'red',  '2022-03-18'),
    ('2', '2023-03-19','math', 'blue', '1990-03-18'),
    ('3', '2021-03-20', 'math', 'blue', '2022-03-19'),
    ('4', '2023-03-21', 'math', 'blue', '2023-07-01'),
    ('5', '2023-03-22', 'math', 'blue', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2023-03-23', 'english', 'red', '2021-07-01'),
    ('1', '2023-03-23', 'english', 'red', '1990-03-18'),
    ('1', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', '1990-03-18'),
    ('3', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', '1990-03-18')
    
    ;
```

A query draft I have, but getting confused on how to handle all the parameters described above:

```
select student_id, class_id, load_timestamp enrolled_start, class_end_date

case when (class_end_date > enrolled_start and enrolled_start is not null) then null else class_end_date end as enrolled_end
from class_enrollments
```

Answer (score 0):

so if we take your input data, and make the "null's" be null, because it makes reading the data easier.

sort it by `student_id`, `class_id`, and `load_timestamp`

```
    ('1', '2021-03-17'::date, 'english', 'red', '2022-03-18', null),
    ('1', '2021-07-01'::date, 'english', 'red',  '2022-03-18', '2021-07-01'),
    ('1', '2023-03-23'::date, 'english', 'red', '2024-03-19', null),
    
    ('1', '2023-03-17'::date, 'math', 'red', '2024-03-18', null),
    ('1', '2023-03-18'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-18', null),
    
    ('1', '2023-03-24'::date, 'science', 'blue', '2024-03-19', null),

    ('2', '2023-03-19'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', null),
    
    ('3', '2021-03-20'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2022-03-19', null),
    
    ('3', '2023-03-24'::date, 'science', 'blue', '2024-03-19', null)

    ('4', '2023-03-21'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', null),
    ('4', '2023-07-01'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', '2023-07-01'),
    
    ('5', '2023-03-22'::date, 'math', 'blue', '2024-03-19', null),
```

and do the same things to the wanted output:

```
    ('1', '2021-03-17', 'english', 'red',  null),
    ('1', '2023-03-23', 'english', 'red', '2021-07-01'),
    ('1', '2023-03-23', 'english', 'red', null),

    ('1', '2023-03-17', 'math', 'red', null),

    ('1', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', null),

    ('2', '2023-03-19','math', 'blue', null),

    ('3', '2021-03-20', 'math', 'blue', '2022-03-19'),

    ('3', '2023-03-24', 'science', 'blue', null)

    ('4', '2023-03-21', 'math', 'blue', '2023-07-01'),

    ('5', '2023-03-22', 'math', 'blue', null),
```

we see that there are only two example of what ever filtering you appear to want.

one for `1, math` and one for `4, math`

`1, math` looks like you might want the earlest start time for the same end time. But `1, english, 2022-3-18` has both rows in the output, and yet `4, math` which is the same pattern as those two `1,english` rows only has one row.

you `2`, `3`, & `5` rows add no knew information to the patterns, so could be removed, and more examples of keeping duplicates, and not keeping duplicates is needed.

Comment: Hmm, let my try and further clarify. For 3 -- it woul d mean that a student enrolled in a math class and finished it and then enrolled in a science class and has not yet finiished it because it is only april in 2023 and the course is planned in end in april of 2024? 

Does that help?